# Auto Layout constraint not working

Tags: ios, xcode, image, autolayout, constraints

Here is the result on the phone:

[image: phone screenshot]

Here is the storyboard:

[image: storyboard screenshot]

No constraint errors register in the log but when I check the logs it returns this image:

[image: error log]

What I don't understand is how come the error log is showing the result I actually want but the phone result does not have the gap under the navbar that I want. I have tried everything in constraints and just can't get it to display the result I am looking for. I have tried turning off "Use auto layout" and "Use size classes", I've tried auto constraints, add missing constraints, added the constraints myself which is what I normally choose and still the same result. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated as I am trying to solve this issue for the last 8 hours or so!!!

I have 2 similar view controllers with the same layout and they are working perfectly. The image on this VC is pulled from FaceBook whereas the other images on the other 2 VC's are being pulled from my database would that make any difference to the final output???

Comment: Did you set "clips to bounds" on the image view? It's a tick box in interface builder.

Comment: I can only find "Clip to SubViews" is that the same?

Comment: Yep that's the one.

Comment: Yes that worked! If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are share your storyboard or xib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ImageView `Clips To Bounds` on storyboard or `.clipsToBounds = YES;` with ObjC or `.clipsToBounds = true` with Swift will solved this issue.